# Create a specified APK version using Angular and Cordova

Tags: android, angular, cordova

I am new to Cordova and am busy with some courses. Please be kind.

I am trying to create an APK that is for Android version 4.3 (Yes, it is old! But this is the only version these devices runs on).

I have read that one must change the config.xml with the necessary build details to build for a specific version, but I am simply not managing. The produced APK can be installed on my phone, but I cannot even see the APK on the device. The only reason I think is because of the APK version.

I am using VS Code and Android Studio (for the emulators).

**What do I need to change, install etc., to build an Android 4.3 APK?**

- Do I need to install a different Cordova (I have the latest)?
- Do I need to install a different Android version for Cordova (cordova platform add android)?
- Do I need to install a specific Android studio API, and how?
- Do I need to change my config.xml?

**Here is my config.xml:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.test.ngcordova" version="4.3.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>ngCordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.2" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="~4.5.4" />
    **<engine name="android" spec="~4.0.0" />**
</widget>
```

Note: This line changes back to `<engine name="android" spec="^7.0.0" />`when I run a build.

Here is a link to my Angular 4 and Cordova [Boilerplate app](https://github.com/onmyway365/ngCordova)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove android platform and then adding the specific platform with the following command 'cordova platform add android@x.x.x' (replacing x.x.x with your version)? Sometimes it overwrites what you have typed in the config.xml when you run the app.

To check if you have the specific API installed you can open the SDK Manager, Android Studio -> Configure -> SDK Manager -> in SDK Platforms you can check if you have Android 4.3 installed. If not, install it. But if you don't have it, you should get an error when you are trying to run the app.

Also, do you get any errors when you are trying do a build?